# How to I launch an activity with an Intent and pass a variable in the new activity?

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, zxing

So right now I'm using the zxing barcode scanner in my app. Here is example code(generic):

```
if(position == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


        }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                // Handle successful scan
                Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, BarcodeScanner.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Handle cancel
            }
        }
    }
```

So when launching the `BarcodeScanner.class`, I also want to pass `contents` into it. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) inside intents to pass data from one activity to the other. In your case, you would have to do something like -

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this,BarcodeScanner.class);

        //load the intent with a key "content" and assign it's value to content            
        intent.putExtra("content",contents);

        //launch the BarcodeScanner activity and send the intent along with it
        //note that content  is passed in as well             
        startActivity(intent);
```

The information is stored in a 'Bundle' object that lives inside the Intent - the Bundle is created when you call the putExtras() method of the Intent object

Answer (score 1):

The same way you passed `"SCAN_MODE"` to the other activity, by calling `putExtra("some key", contents)` before calling `startActivity()`, and then inside BarcodeScanner call `this.getIntent().getStringExtra("some key")`